# Time::Piece limited to years < 2038

Tags: perl

i'm using [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to parse date.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $date = '20-11-2038';
my $frmt = '%d-%m-%Y';

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, $frmt);

$t = $t + ONE_DAY;
print $t->ymd('/'), "\n";
```

i can use only dates ranging from 1970 - 2038. if i use any other date, i'm getting error as

```
Day too big - 25160 > 24853
Cannot handle date (0, 0, 0, 20, 11, 2038) at C:/perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 315
```

is there any other way ?

Comment: You'll need at least perl `5.12` https://eval.in/194009

Comment: Time to upgrade, https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv

Comment: i'm using portable version of perl ! not an installer version. how to get upgraded version of the same ?

Comment: http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html (PortableZIP)

Comment: Welcome to the limits of a 32-bit signed `time_t` value. 2038 is going to be a really bad year for a lot of software.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, I get:

```
Argument "ONE_DAY" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ...lib/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Time/Piece.pm line 571.
```

But, if I add `use Time::Seconds` it works fine (I changed the code to show dates outside the 1970-2038 range):

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $tmin = Time::Piece->strptime('20-11-1970', '%d-%m-%Y');
my $tmax = Time::Piece->strptime('20-11-2038', '%d-%m-%Y');
say $tmin->ymd('-');
say $tmax->ymd('-');
say '---';
my $tmin2 = $tmin - ONE_YEAR;
my $tmax2 = $tmax + ONE_YEAR;
say $tmin2->ymd('-');
say $tmax2->ymd('-');
```

and the result is:

```
1970-11-20
2038-11-20
---
1969-11-19
2039-11-20
```

Update:

```
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Time::Piece is up to date. (1.29)
```